# How to use nested builder pattern in json?

Tags: json, design-patterns, builder-pattern

I have a JSON object:

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "category": "developer",
    "Address": [
      {
        "street": "xxx"
      },
      {
        "street": "yyy"
      }
    ]
  },
  ........
]
```

I am using **builder pattern** to build `Address` as well as the object of this array. How can I append one more *street* in `Address` in this structure (given `name` is *unique* across different objects of this array.

> Note:  As I am using builder pattern so I can not access fields of
>   this object using getters.

​